# Problems with remove() since replacing live() with on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been using a script with jQuery 1.7 with the `live()` method here:

https://jsfiddle.net/anacaona83/umpdv484/

The `remove()` action with label "Supprimer" is all right.

When I try it with jQuery 2.x it does not work anymore so I changed `live()` to `on()` but then, the remove action does not work anymore:

https://jsfiddle.net/anacaona83/d87cj64L/

But the remove action does work when the

```
<TH> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Supprimer</a></TH>
```

Is not in the

```
javascript $(function() {
```

But in the HTML.

This is a problem because I really need to `remove()` the new `<tr>` I have created with the `.appendTo()` method.

Comment: You can't just replace `.live` with `.on` - you need to read how it works. `.on` expects a container that is in the DOM at the time of binding to work. - https://jsfiddle.net/d87cj64L/2/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. Instead, put an [MCVE](/help/mcve) **in** the question (ideally using Stack Snippets, the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: Put your code in the actual question. Please don't put links

Comment: Thanks for all your advices so I will do better next time :) This was my first questions. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `on()` to the parent element which is in the DOM on load of the page - your `scntDiv` element. Then you provide the selector of the element the event will be raised on in the second parameter, like this:

```
scntDiv.on('click', '#remScnt', function() {
    // your code...
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d87cj64L/1/)

Also note that you are appending elements with the same `id` attribute which will make the HTML of the page invalid, you should change those to classes.

Comment: ++ for changing elements that have the same id into classes if we press the 'add' button multiple times, there are multiple elements with the `id` -> `remScnt` present on the page. every `id` needs to be unique.  as a side note, to learn more about event delegation, go here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This is very helpful as I am not at all a programmer...

Comment: No problem,  glad to help.